# How to get custom user status from discord

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to get custom user status from discord gateway but it only prints one status from one user, I want all of them.

```
payload = {
    'op': 2,
    "d": {
        "token": TOKEN,
        "intents": 513,
        "properties": {
            "$os": "windows",
            "$browser": "chrome",
            "$device": "pc"
        }
    },
}

send_json_requests(ws, payload)
response = recieve_json_respone(ws)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start using discord.py documentation.

I would do something like this:

```
async def customstatus():
    guild = client.get_guild(* GUILD ID *)
    for member in guild.members:
        # Do some stuff
```

More information regarding CustomActivity :

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#customactivity